# MemoryError when sending some photos in telegram bot

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I created a telegram bot and it sends some photos to user.
It works good in 4 or 5 photos but after that it crashes.
I send photos like this:

```
for i in range(len(pages)):
        photo = open('pics/{0}.jpg'.format(i+1), 'rb')
        bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id,photo=photo)
```

this is my error:

```
2019-03-13 14:30:52,207 (util.py:65 WorkerThread2) ERROR - TeleBot: "MemoryError occurred, args=()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Env/pdf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 59, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "pdf.py", line 63, in handle_docs
    pages = convert_from_path('botpdf.pdf', 500)
  File "/root/Env/pdf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pdf2image/pdf2image.py", line 98, in convert_from_path
    data, err = proc.communicate()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1072, in communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1745, in _communicate
    stdout = b''.join(stdout)
MemoryError
"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pdf.py", line 99, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=False, interval=0)
  File "/root/Env/pdf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 389, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
  File "/root/Env/pdf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 413, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "/root/Env/pdf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 108, in raise_exceptions
    six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])
  File "/root/Env/pdf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/root/Env/pdf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 59, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "pdf.py", line 63, in handle_docs
    pages = convert_from_path('botpdf.pdf', 500)
  File "/root/Env/pdf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pdf2image/pdf2image.py", line 98, in convert_from_path
    data, err = proc.communicate()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1072, in communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1745, in _communicate
    stdout = b''.join(stdout)
MemoryError
```

Comment: I'de suggest you separate your read/write operations, first read the image, and better do it in chunks and serve it chunk by chunk to your converter.
Also try to use a context manager to open your files, one by one and close them.

Answer (score 0):

Use an output directory, your current usage of `pdf2image` loads all the images in memory. This can have a huge impact!

Where you wrote `pages = convert_from_path('botpdf.pdf', 500)`

Change it for:

```
import tempfile

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as path:
    pages = convert_from_path('botpdf.pdf', 500, output_folder=path)
```

This will write all the converted images to disk before returning them to you (saving a huge chunk of memory). You can also convert to JPEG instead of the default PPM (which is a raw format):

```
pages = convert_from_path('botpdf.pdf', 500, fmt='jpeg')
```

But with this solution you will still have issues if the PDF is very large.

Comment: Yes it works but it still has that issue. I can't send many photos. 
Can you suggest something about that?